# Disabled Timer Job Still Running

Tags: timer-jobs

I have a disabled timer job that is still running and can't figure out why. Below is a screenshot of it showing with the "Enable" button an option, implying it's disabled. There's also a screenshot showing it disabled in the list of timer jobs. It's creating a log file, with dates/times where it's disabled. Any ideas on why it might still be running?
[image: Job1]
[image: Job 2]

Answer (score 1):

I'm answering my own question: I made sure that it ran at 8:00 a.m. - it did. I then restarted the SharePoint Timer service, and it did NOT run at 8:15. Seems odd I should have to do that, but it seems to have done the trick.

Comment: Worked for me as well - thanks for actually returning and answering your own question. :)